# Beast Mode to Convert text to date

Tags: domo

I am trying to convert a string to date...

```
STR_TO_DATE(`MFGDTE`,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

But I am getting the value as `2019-12-18t00:00-06:00`. Can you please let me know how to get just the date `2019-12-18`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `STR_TO_DATE()` function actually returns a `DateTime` object, not just a `Date`, but it's easy to convert to a `Date` and remove the time component, like this:

```
DATE(STR_TO_DATE(`MFGDTE`,'%Y-%m-%d'))
```

which will return, e.g. `2019-12-18`.